# Split url code in c#

Tags: c#-3.0

I want to split a URL using the following code:

```
string url="http://images/newyork/1550/t_2911340.JPG";
file_name=server.MapPath("~/storedImages/")+"t_2911340.gif";
save_file_from_url(file_name,url);
```

But I want my code like this:

```
file_name=server.MapPath("~/storedImages/") +
    ( values after last / from url and before ) +
     gif // by adding gif i want to rename it
```

Can you help me to split the code and append it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

See [the System.Uri class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Construct an instance of `System.Uri`, passing your URL string to the constructor. Then access the various properties of the Uri object as your "split" URL. To further split the path portion of the URL into segments, use the [Segments Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Also System.UriBuilder: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx